# how do I use the calendar class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming. When i enter the following code into the IDLE3 shell it works fine. When I save it and run it as a module or through the Terminal it returns the following error:

> File "/home/pi/Python_Programs/calendar.py", line 4, in 
>       calendar.prmonth(2016, i)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'prmonth'

Here is my code:

```
import calendar

for i in range(1, 13):
    calendar.prmonth(2016, i)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you named your module **calendar.py** - Python is attempting to load `prmonth` from your own module, not from the actual calendar module - you have effectively shadowed it.

Simply name your module something else such that `prmonth` is accessed from the actual calendar module.